# why not work image mapster with jquery 3.1.1?

Tags: jquery, image, dictionary, area

I'm trying to implement image Mapster in my project but does not work with the version of jquery 3.1.1 only works with version 1.6 I only use this version that greatly affects the performance of my project, they know of any solution?

Comment: They most surtainly changed something in jQuery 1.6. Are you sure 1.6 is the last update where it still works?

Comment: the latest version in the works is 2.4, but it causes the same conflicts that 1.6 for this reason I want to know if it is possible to adapt Mapster 3 or later versions